kendo grid setOptions - how to handle breaking changes to grid schema?
I have a ASP.NET MVC Kendo Grid with possibility to save column order and visibility, similar to this example
Grid options are persisted to database. Existing options reference specific column which I want to remove. Removing this column in my C# class causes grid to fail on  grid load with an error:

ReferenceError: ColumnName is not defined
at eval (eval at compile (kendo.all.js:234:30), :3:3247)
at init._rowsHtml (kendo.all.js:70687:37)
at init._renderContent (kendo.all.js:71510:34)

ColumnName is a property that is used in column client template, like this: #= ColumnName #
Is it possible to resolve such discrepancies silently during setOptions call? It would be good to remove columns that are not part of the current grid model automatically. Or maybe there is an option to ignore client template during setOptions?
Currently, I see only two bad options - always delete persisted settings for all users to ensure everyone is up to date, or write a migration function that will consume options object and modify it according to current schema by removing outdated columns.

I figured out that instead of "blindly" applying possibly invalid options, I can use them to reorder and/or hide columns in grid. So instead of grid.setOptions(options), I use this code
options.columns.forEach(function (e, i) {
    let gridColumn = grid.columns[i];
    if (gridColumn && gridColumn.field !== e.field) {
        let gridColumnByField = grid.columns.find(x => x.field === e.field);

        if (gridColumnByField) {
            grid.reorderColumn(i, gridColumnByField);
        }
    }
                        
    if (e.hidden) {
        grid.hideColumn(e.field);
    }
});

